# How to create tnsnames.ora on windows 7 for oracle12c client?

Tags: oracle12c, tnsnames

I have installed Oracle12c client on windows7, I am not able to find tnsnames.ora file on my system.

Comment: Where is your Oracle Home directory?

Comment: its in d:/app/client/..

Comment: It should be located in TNS_ADMIN path. To get the path run : `echo %TNS_ADMIN%` from  command prompt.